# what is the biggest known functional distance between an enhancer and its target gene (TSS) in cis?

Tags: genetics, gene-expression, transcription-factor

since the title seems self explanatory;
It would be nice if anybody could provide a reference. I'm looking for a paper that I belive stated around 1.5 Mb but anything above will be cordialy welcomed.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found 1.5 Mb, but 1 Megabase. This is the case for the shh gene in chicken, where the enhancer element is located 1 Mb upstream. The original article can be found here:

- ["A long-range Shh enhancer regulates expression in the developing
  limb and fin and is associated with preaxial polydactyly."](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12837695)

There are two reviews which are also interesting in this context:

- [When needles look like hay: How to find tissue-specific enhancers in
  model organism genomes](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012160610012315)
- [Remote control of gene expression.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17403687)

Comment: thanks. I also have encountered 1 Mb and distances slightly above, but I'm specifically interested in the longest known functional distance in cis. it is not as easy as I thought since I have spend now several hours on ncbi/pubmed ...

Comment: I can have an additional look later today. Do you have any idea in which organism or for which gene this has been described?

Comment: unfortunately i don't. i may belive belive it was in M.m - but then again if I remembered properly I would have found it by now. thanks again anyway

Comment: this paper "Extensive Promoter-Centered Chromatin Interactions Provide a Topological Basis for Transcription Regulation" at least states finding interaction-distances in the range of megabases... and leaves it at that.

Comment: I stumbled upon a few of these claims but they never show data or have references for it.

Comment: i found "On a chromosome far, far away"  and " Extensive promoter-
centered chromatin interactions provide a topological basis for transcription regulation.
". one of the papers claimed multiple Mbp and the other stated a range of 2-3Mbp. they did provide their 'not-fully-raw' data bu I have not yet calculated myself. anyhow, since it was I think you who recomended at least one of these two papers in another forum (what are the chances) I thank you